# While running as a jar application, Not able to access static files in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, fatjar

I have a basic springboot application with the following folder structure. inside webapps i have some images and css.

[image]

If i run it using my Intellij IDE, I am able to access images and css

at `localhost:8080/images/test.png`

But if i create a fat jar and run it using `java -jar demo.jar` then i am not able to access these images or css folders

This is how i am building my jar using maven plugin

```
   <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>css/default.css</include>
                    <include>images/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How can i make sure that these images and css files will be available when running as a jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the case of a JAR-file, `src/main/webapp` has no special meaning. It's not recommended to use it according to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.static-content):

> Do not use the `src/main/webapp` directory if your application is packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it works **only** with war packaging, and it is silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.

The way you can make this work is by treating `src/main/webapp` as a normal **classpath directory**. You did that by adding the `<resources>` tag.

However, Spring boot only serves static content from certain folders (`/public`, `/static` or `/META-INF/resources`). Since you didn't put your files in such a folder, they aren't served by Spring boot.

To solve this, you need to put your files within either **src/main/resources/public** (recommended) or **src/main/webapp/public**. If moving the files isn't an option, you can also change Maven to put it in that directory for you:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <targetPath>public/</targetPath> <!-- Add this -->
        <includes>
            <include>css/default.css</include>
            <include>images/*</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Its working now. targetPath was the one that i was missing. After adding that it works fine

Comment: It was working from my windows machine with oracle jdk-15. But when i run the same jar in wsl with openjdk15, it wont work. Is there anything specific to os or jdk

Comment: Well i got the same error  with wsl and oraclejdk15. So it must be the OS compatibility issue

Answer (score 0):

Put custom files in `resources/static`.

I host a **Spring Boot application in Docker** on my VPS. This code will work on a local system whilst developing in an IDE **as well as if the .JAR-file is wrapped in a Docker image**:

Example case:

I like to get a PDF. The PDf document is located at `static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF`.

1.) Wire the class `ResourceLoader`

```java
private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public MyService(@Autowired ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}
```

2.) Create a resource by `pathOfAttachment` (`String`)

```java
String pathOfAttachment = "classpath:static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF"
Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(pathOfAttachment);
```

`Resource` is an interface that extends `InputStreamSource` as you can see in the documentation:

`public interface Resource extends InputStreamSource`

Source: `org.springframework.core.io` [Link to documentation (click here)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)

3.) Get file

```java
String fileName = resource.getFilename();
File file = resource.getFile();
```